# ActiveMQ support for TLSv1.2

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, tls1.2

I'm trying to get ActiveMQ to support a TLSv1.2.  I'm using activemq v5.14.5.  The fix talked about in [Create ActiveMQ Connection on TLS1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870380/create-activemq-connection-on-tls1-2) did not work.  When I stepped through the code I see that the

```
        context.setSSLContext(sslContext);
        SslContext.setCurrentSslContext(context);
        Connection connection = factory.createConnection(loginName, pwd);
```

call to factory.createConnection() actually doesn't use the value that was just set, but instead creates a new SSL context using the hard coded default of "TLS".  I observed this in the debugger.

Any other suggestions are welcome.  I think the topic "configuring transports" at http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html may hold the solution but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default embedded ActiveMQ broker configuration does not create an SSL transport connector. If you manually added an SSL transport connector, then you may have restricted the SSL protocols supported by the broker using the option transport.enabledProtocols:

```
<transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://localhost:61617?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2"></transportConnector>
```

This configuration restricts the SSL connector of ActiveMQ to only support TLSv1.2. Other TLSv1, TLSv1.1, SSLv3 will not be supported.